# Is there a way to prevent objects from clipping through one another?

Tags: animation, workflow

I have a scene I'm working on where my character is getting up and out of a chair continuously, putting their hands on a wall, etc. It's kind of tedious to go through and make sure the actor doesn't clip through the object every time, so I'm wondering if there is a way to get the actor and the chair to interact.

Basically, what I'm trying to do, is be able to push the actor up against the chair and it stop upon making contact. Is this something that can be solved with physics simulations? I'm pretty amateur when it comes to most things with Blender, but physics is a whole other monster I've yet to conquer.

I have vague memories of doing something like this in the past, but I think it was with a singular object and I was only modeling. With this I have multiple objects and an actor that I want to interact with them.

If you took time out of your day to read this, I thank you, hope all is well.

Comment: Add a collision modifier to the wall?

Comment: i think physics simulation is over the top for that. in my experience a little bit of clipping is good to give the illusion of contact. and you only should worry about it when it's visible (like in a close up shot). Also copy/pasting poses can save you some time